# Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a few objects and I want to create a 'map' array to store the object with one field key as an array which will have two input and a value field. The value field will be the sum of every map that has the same 'key' property. I try some solution and it didn't work.

```
var myJSON = [{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : null,
  TotalAmount : 0
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201907',
  service : 'License',
  TotalAmount : 5000000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'License',
  TotalAmount : 5000000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'Package',
  TotalAmount : 1200000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'Package',
  TotalAmount : 3000000
}]

var labels = [], dataPackage = [], dataLisence = [];
var TotalAmountP = 0;
var TotalAmountL = 0;
var map = [{ key : ['Service','TimeCheck'], value : 0 }];

for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {

    if (labels.indexOf(myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2)) == -1) {
        labels.push(myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2));
        map[i].key[1] = myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2);
    }

    if (myJSON[i].Service == "Package") {
        map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].Service;

        for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
            if (map[i].key[0] !== map[j].key[0] && map[i].key[1] !== map[j].key[1]) {
                map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].Service;
                map[i].value = myJSON[i].TotalAmount;
            } else {
                var newValue = map[j].value + myJSON[i].TotalAmount
                map[j].value = newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (myJSON[i].Service == "License") {

        map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].Service;

        for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
            if (map[i].key[0] !== map[j].key[0] && map[i].key[1] !== map[j].key[1]) {
                map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].Service;
                map[i].value = myJSON[i].TotalAmount;
            } else {
                var newValue = map[j].value + myJSON[i].TotalAmount
                map[j].value = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The map array should have two value:

```
map[0] = {
key: ['Package','201907'],
value: 4200000}
map[1] = {
key: ['License','201907'],
value: 5000000}
```

and so on.

Comment: Because you are iterating on `myJson` which has length 5 and `map` has length 2. from index 3 it will give you an error. You need to handle `map undefined` in for loop

Comment: i just check the code on another platform and it said the error start at the line map[i].key[1] = myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2);

Comment: Yes exactly, `map[i]` will be undefined when your index or `i` will be 3.

Answer (score 0):

You say the map array only has two values: in your code it is initialized with only one value, at index 0. But you are iterating with the variable `i` up to the length of `myJSON`, which has 5 values. So when you access `map[i].key`, and `i` is `1`, `map[i]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating on `myJSON` which has length more than `map`. So you would not access `map[3]` and that will give you `key` is not found from `undefined`

Check below solution.

```js
var map = [{
key: ['Package','201907'],
value: 4200000},
{
key: ['License','201907'],
value: 5000000}]


var myJSON = [{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : null,
  TotalAmount : 0
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201907',
  service : 'License',
  TotalAmount : 5000000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'License',
  TotalAmount : 5000000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'Package',
  TotalAmount : 1200000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'Package',
  TotalAmount : 3000000
}]

var labels = [], dataPackage = [], dataLisence = [];
var TotalAmountP = 0;
var TotalAmountL = 0;
var map = [{ key : ['Service','TimeCheck'], value : 0 }];

for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {

    if (labels.indexOf(myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2)) == -1) {
        labels.push(myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2));
        map[i].key[1] = myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2);
    }

    if (myJSON[i].service == "Package") {
        map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].service;

        for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
            if (map[i].key[0] !== map[j].key[0] && map[i].key[1] !== map[j].key[1]) {
                map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].service;
                map[i].value = myJSON[i].TotalAmount;
            } else {
                var newValue = map[j].value + myJSON[i].TotalAmount
                map[j].value = newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (myJSON[i].service == "License") {

        map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].service;

        for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
            if (map[i].key[0] !== map[j].key[0] && map[i].key[1] !== map[j].key[1]) {
                map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].service;
                map[i].value = myJSON[i].TotalAmount;
            } else {
                var newValue = map[j].value + myJSON[i].TotalAmount
                map[j].value = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(map);
```

Comment: Hi @hardik, the solution is cool but the query is related to handle the map array while iterating the myJSON object

Answer (score 0):

The very first step is to make the map array structure length equal to myJSON value which is 5, then only you can iterate the map array.

```
var map = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
  map.push({ key : ['service','TimeCheck'], value : 0 }); 
}
```

Another mistake you made in your code is for key name is not myJSON[i].Service .
It is actually myJSON[i].service
's' should be smaller, the key name is case insensitive

I have also removed the following for if the condition doesn't know the exact reason for adding the same inside if the condition. You can also you it as per your need.

```
map[i].key[1] = myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2);
```

```js
var myJSON = [{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : null,
  TotalAmount : 0
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201907',
  service : 'License',
  TotalAmount : 5000000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'License',
  TotalAmount : 5000000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'Package',
  TotalAmount : 1200000
},
{
  TimeCheck : '201908',
  service : 'Package',
  TotalAmount : 3000000
}]


var labels = [], dataPackage = [], dataLisence = [];
var TotalAmountP = 0;
var TotalAmountL = 0;

var map = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
  map.push({ key : ['service','TimeCheck'], value : 0 }); 
}

for (var i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {

    if (labels.indexOf(myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2)) == -1) {
        labels.push(myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2));
        //map[i].key[1] = myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2);
    }

    map[i].key[1] = myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(0, 4) + '/' + myJSON[i].TimeCheck.substr(4, 2);


    if (myJSON[i].service === "Package") {
        map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].service;

        for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
            if (map[i].key[0] !== map[j].key[0] && map[i].key[1] !== map[j].key[1]) {
                map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].service;
                map[i].value = myJSON[i].TotalAmount;
            } else {
                var newValue = map[j].value + myJSON[i].TotalAmount
                map[j].value = newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (myJSON[i].service === "License") {

        map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].service;

        for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
            if (map[i].key[0] !== map[j].key[0] && map[i].key[1] !== map[j].key[1]) {
                map[i].key[0] = myJSON[i].service;
                map[i].value = myJSON[i].TotalAmount;
            } else {
                var newValue = map[j].value + myJSON[i].TotalAmount
                map[j].value = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(map)
```